# US usage of 'mad'

Tags: american-english, british-english

When Americans say something like, "Are you mad at me?", is there any difference between that and, "Are you angry at me?"

To me, as a Brit, 'mad' means 'insane'. Saying, "Are you mad at me?" should indicate an even greater state of anger than usual, such that it actually drives the person insane.

Comment: Would that not be _angry **with** me_ and _angry **at** this situation_ ?

Comment: You're a madman!  It's not a nasty corruption at all.

Comment: You must have your tongue in your cheek to ask such a simple question as a native speaker....

Comment: It should be understood that there is "Mad Magazine", a satire magazine that was first published in the 50s and which gained great popularity with teenagers.  It caused "mad" to gain several different meanings.

Comment: 'It should be noted, however, that Shakespeare used mad to mean “crazy” much more frequently than he used it to mean “angry.”' [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/can-mad-mean-angry)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usage of *mad* to mean "insane" is considered a Briticism in America—go figure. Yet *mad* is actually a very diverse word.  As an [adjective](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mad), *mad* can mean *insane*, *furious*, *rabid*, *wild*, *frantic*, even *hilarious*.  The use of *mad* to mean ["beside oneself with anger"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mad) dates back to the 14th century. Rev. John Witherspoon, a Scottish-born signatory of the Declaration of Independence, dismissed that usage as an "Americanism" in 1781.  I guess we Americans have ourselves to blame.

Comment: I thought it was 'Britishism'.

Comment: [Briticism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Briticism); Britishism is considered an alternate form.

Comment: This appears to be a Briti-schism.

Comment: Wow. This word's got [mad](http://mad.urbanup.com/1005004) definitions, yo.

Comment: @jgbelacqua - Brilliant. +1

Comment: *"The usage of mad to mean "insane" is considered a Briticism in America."* Really? Reference? In my experience both meanings are used in the US.

Answer (score 5):

I would say the British can use Mad as a synonym for angry – at least locally. According to the [OED](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/mad_adj#eid):

> 6b. Angry, irate, cross. Also, in
> weakened sense: annoyed, exasperated
> (with †against, at, with, etc.). Now
> colloq. (chiefly N. Amer.) and Brit.
> regional.

Answer (score 3):

As a native Brit, I frequently use *Mad* to mean both *Angry* and *Insane*... particularly when I am at work(!).

I don't think there is much of a trans-Atlantic distinction in meaning.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, my own American sense of 'mad' vs. 'angry' is that 'mad' is a mild form of 'anger'.  If I'm mad at someone, it's a low degree of anger, greater than 'annoyed', but less than outright 'angry'.  After 'angry', would come 'really mad'.  Then perhaps, 'livid' or 'furious'.

Edit: I also think that perhaps they carry different time frames with them.  'Mad' is more temporary and might be expected to fade sooner.

Comment: "Mad" is certainly often used of quite trivial upsets. "Angry" isn't very serious either - it's often qualified as "very angry" which suggests that without "very" it's mild, and there are more serious words like "irate" or "livid".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call that as a nasty corruption. Because, the word *mad*, with the meaning of *angry*, belongs to American English. A word or phrase of one dialect may sound weird/incorrect for the other.

As a matter of fact, *mad* to mean *angry* is [still a regional word in UK](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mad).

Comment: The word changed in British English, with Americans retaining the original meaning which is now rarely used in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

An update on the usage of 'mad'--
Beginning in California and moving eastward across the US we have 'mad' as an intensifier:  She was mad funny!  That was mad crazy.  The guy is mad stupid.

Comment: We do? Reference for the existence of that geographical difference?

Answer (score 0):

American children usually say “mad.”  American adults generally say “angry,” and are likely to know the difference.  A right-wing millionaire here in Texas had a radio campaign in the 1970’s that went, “I’m Eddie Chiles, and I’m mad!”  He was, of course, angry about what he perceived as left-wing nonsense, but in his case, maybe he was so angry that it bordered on insanity.

Of course, Americans also use *mad* in its more traditional sense.  A *mad dog* is a rabid dog, a *madman* is a lunatic, a *mad cow* has BSE, and *madcap* means pushing the edge of reason.

Comment: *'American adults generally say “angry,” and are likely to know the difference.'* As one American, I disagree with both assertions.

Answer (score 0):

As a kid I would use the word mad when I was disturbed. As an adult I've moved towards using it more for mental state; insane.

Comment: Without knowing where you grew up it's difficult to see how this answers the question.